# iOS - How to keep two or more objects horizontally centered while maintaining the space between them?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, alignment

I am working on a sign-up page. At the bottom of the page I want to add a label says : "Have an account?" and a button with title "Log In".

The result I'm trying to accomplish here is that this line "Have an account? Log In" will always be centered no matter what screen size of the device is. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to come up with a solution with constraint and alignment settings in storyboard.

Can anyone offer me some help?

Comment: I believe you should be able to drop those two controls into their own separate view, then just horizontally center the view. BUT, I don't know if that is the best/correct way to do it, so we'll see if anyone says anything else.

Comment: @j.f. that was the first thing that came to mind for me as well. I don't see any reason why this would be frowned upon, as you're basically treating the 2 objects as one entity, so dropping into their own view would be perfectly acceptable. It would also be incredibly easy to set up, which is a nice plus.

Comment: Here is good answer about 2 labels and constraint between them, it will be good start for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20808830/2204866

Comment: I'm new with objective-c or any coding. What do you mean by dropping into their own view? these two objects are in one view.

Comment: @StanG, on your storyboard, drag and drop another view onto your view controller. Just like you would a button or a label, you should see an object called "View". Once it is resized, drag your button and label onto that new view.

Comment: @StanG, since you are new to iOS development, I would highly recommend [Ray Wenderlich's tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials) if you haven't come across them already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could drag and drop a new view onto your view controller and place the button and label on that view. Then resize the new view to fit the content. Finally, horizontally center the view.

Now instead of having to horizontally center the two controls, you are only centering their container, thus preserving their layout.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly:

Select an object, click on the align button in the bottom right of your storyboard window

And add a constraint "Horizontal centre in container"